# Python/Q#: Module not found error, with .qs file in the same directory

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors, q#

Lately I started working with Q# and python as host language. I was working on a project and everything seemed fine. Suddenly I get the error "module not found" and I seem to get it in all my previous projects too.

So I have a directory: C:\Users\Username\Q#projects
In this folder I have 2 files: HostProtocol.py, which is the main file, and BB84.qs, which is the file from which I want to import.

The HostProtocol.py file looks like this:

```
import qsharp

from Quantum.BB84 import Run_BB84Protocol
Run_BB84Protocol.simulate()
```

The BB84.qs file looks like this:

```
namespace Quantum.BB84 {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;

function Run_BB84Protocol() Unit{... the code from the function...}
}
```

When I try to run HostProtocol.py I get the following error message:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'Quantum'
  File "C:\Users\Username\Q#projects\HostProtocol.py", line 3, in 
    from Quantum.BB84 import Run_BB84Protocol

And this is for all my previous projects too. It's very frustrating and I have no clue what could have caused it because it worked fine previously. Any help is definitely welcome!

Comment: Did you install Quantum and did you activate the corresponding environment? Which package manager and IDE are you using?

Comment: Quantum is just a name used in the namespace, it is not an actual package. In all the tutorials I followed they used it so I thought at first it was necassary. Even if I remove it, it doesn't work. I'm using Visual studio code, but even running from the cmd line doesn't work.

Comment: So why are you trying to import Quantum then (HostProtocol.py, line 3) and what do you think does "ModuleNotFound" actually mean?

Comment: I'm trying to import a function. This function is found in the namespace called Quantum.BB84. This namespace is found in the file BB84.qs . The namespace name can be whatever, I thought it was maybe the Quantum. in the name that produced the problem, then again it never did before. But I changed it to just BB84 for example and still got the error ModuleNotFound but this time it's BB84 module thats not found. I don't know why I suddenly got this error because everything worked fine before. But now nothing works anymore, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: This is a misconception: You simply can't directly import a function from your BB84.qs into Python.

Comment: But why did it work before? I could easily import my functions from Q# by using from namespacename import functionname. It always worked until recently.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any Q# compilation errors in your Q# source file, your Q# operations and functions will not be available. Check your Python output for errors. When I run the sample code you provided, it reports a syntax error in the Q# code (there's a missing colon before the return type `Unit`):

```
 fail: Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp.Workspace[0]
       QS3211: Invalid return type annotation. The argument tuple needs to be followed
       by a colon and the return type of the callable.
```